# How to Stop Video in ios Which Throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer

Here is my code which I am using for playing a video,
I need to stop the video on button click but it throw EXC_BAD_ACCESS Exception, I get the following message in Log

***message sent to deallocated instance***

```
-(void) getallData{
    NSString * video=[dict valueForKey:@"abc"];
    NSString *strvideo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@XXXX/XXX/%@",appDelegate.baseURL,video];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString: strvideo];
    avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
    avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
    avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(2, 45, 724, 450);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:avplayerLayer];
    [viewObj.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
    [avPlayer play];
}

-(IBAction)btnBackClick:(id)sender
{
    //I need to stop video here  
    [avPlayer pause];
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error message?

Comment: @stevekohls :Thread 1: `EXC_BAD_ACESS(CODE=1,address=0x1xxxxd40)` . And When i Enable Zombie Object `-[AVPlayer pause]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1xxxxxxd0`

Comment: How is `avPlayer` declared?

Comment: `@implementation                                                                                   AVPlayer * avPlayer;`

Comment: it show (_NSZombie_AVPlayer) when is hover over object

Comment: Is `viewObj` weak? The error message says the object is already deallocated but it could also be a parent object.

Comment: how can check that  
Is `viewObj` weak?

Comment: Check the declaration and check it also in Instruments.

Comment: i have declared it as  `UIView * viewObj;` in implementation does that mean is it weak??

Comment: Try to declare both `objView` and `avPlayer` as (strong) properties.

Comment: it didn't helped making both strong

Comment: Declare `AVPlayer * avPlayer` as `Strong` property and in `header file .h`

Comment: @pkc456 : still crashing